# Need to create custom validation in Qualtrics limited to format "xx.x%"

Tags: regex, validation, qualtrics

I'm trying to create custom validation in Qualtrics using "matches regex" (though i'm open to any other alternatives which achieve the same result in Qualtrics).  The allowed format should be: x.x, xx.x, x.x% or xx.x%

For example, 8.4 or 8.4% should be allowed.  I've tried the following:

```
^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1})?%?$

^[0-9]{1,2}([\.][0-9]{1})?[\%]?$
```

Both seem to work fine in an online regex tester (https://regex101.com/) but I can't get them working in Qualtrics which seems to treat anything submitted as invalid.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've never used Qualtrics, so I'm not sure if this is correct, but try replacing your backslashes \, with double backslashes, \\ So, try using this `^[0-9]{1,2}([\\.][0-9]{1})?[\\%]?$`

Comment: No go.  Still having the same issue.  Thanks for taking a crack at it anyway!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in Qualtrics:

```
^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1})?%?$
```